# How to convert level 2 indexes to be columns index dataframe with pandas or etc

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

my first dataframe is like this:

|  |  | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| idx1 | idx2 |  |
| 1 | a | 9 |
|  | b | 8 |
| 2 | a | 7 |
|  | b | 6 |

i want to convert into like this:

| idx1 | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | 8 |
| 2 | 7 | 6 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a MultiIndex, you need to convert to Series and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df['value'].unstack('idx2').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

output:

```
   idx1  a  b
0     1  9  8
1     2  7  6
```

used input:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame({'value': {(1, 'a'): 9, (1, 'b'): 8, (2, 'a'): 7, (2, 'b'): 6}})
        .rename_axis(['idx1', 'idx2'])
      )
```